# How to create a torrent and share with others?

Tags: bittorrent

I don't know a lot about torrents, i am just a user, have utorrent, i search the web and download torrents using it.

What i want now is to create torrents and share my files with others, whats steps i should follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can create a torrent file with utorrent. Then you have to upload it to a tracker, and then redownload the tweaked torrent file (it will contain the tracker information). After it you just simply keep seeding for users.

Answer (score 9):

[Jeff](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000978.html) himself actually blogged about this when setting up the torrent for the StackOverflow database. He posted the how to [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001272.html)